# "No route to host" error when client sends request to server (C Networking)

Tags: c, sockets, networking, client-server, network-protocols

I have a basic client/server setup in C which works only if the client and the server are on the same machine. Is there any reason why my client wouldn't be able to send a request to my server if they are on different machines?

In this instance I am running my server on a virtual machine and trying to run the client on my host machine.

Observations:

- If I start my server on my VM, and also run the client on the VM and change its address 
  in the client code so that there is a line that says

  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("**127.0.0.1**");

  then my server is able to connect with my client. There is no error here and everything occurs as it should.
- If I start my server on my VM, but then run my client on my host machine with my VM's IP instead:

  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("**172.16.225.130**");

  then this causes an error. The output of trying to run my client as my server runs is:

  **connect error: No route to host**
- **NOTE:** I am able to ping my VM at 172.16.225.130 from my host machine and get a response successfully. But I am NOT able to telnet my VM successfully. It produces the same "No route to host" error.

**Server code on virtual machine with IP: 172.16.225.130**

```
int main() {

  int sfd, cfd;
  int ch = 'k';
  int optval = 1;
  /* sockaddr_in holds IP address and port info*/
  struct sockaddr_in saddr, caddr;


  sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /* set struct sockaddr_in saddr fields */
  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Set address family to IPv4 Internet */
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any internet address */
  saddr.sin_port = htons(29008); /* Set server port to 29008 */

  setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);

  /* Bind address to the socket (sfd) created */
  bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

  listen(sfd, 1);

  while (1) {

        printf("Server waiting...\n");

        cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL);

        /* Read character from client */
        if (read(cfd, &ch, 1) < 0) perror("read");

        printf("Read character: %c\n from client\n", ch);

        ch++;

        /* Send incremented character to client */
        if (write(cfd, &ch, 1) < 0) perror ("write");

        printf("Sent character: %c\n to client\n", ch);

        /* Close connection with client by closing the client fd */
        close(cfd);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Client code on my host machine**

```
int main() {

  int cfd;

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  char ch = 'r';

  cfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;


  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.16.225.130");

  addr.sin_port = htons(29008);


  if (connect(cfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("connect error");
        return -1;
  }


  if (write(cfd, &ch, 1) < 0) perror("write");
  if (read(cfd, &ch, 1) < 0) perror("read");
  printf("nReply from Server: %cnn\n", ch);
  close(cfd);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Here are things I've tried already and still do not work.

**1.** Opened up port 29008 in my VM:

Appended rule in my /etc/sysconfig/iptables file:

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 29008 -j ACCEPT

Saved and closed the file. Restarted iptables:

/etc/init.d/iptables restart

**2.** Allowed requests to be received by each other by configuring firewall settings:

On VM: sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.225.1 -j ACCEPT

On host: sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.225.130 -j ACCEPT

**3.** Turned off my iptables on my VM completely. This produced a different result. Instead of a "No route to host" error occuring, running my client causes it to just hang.

Comment: This may not be a programming issue. Make sure your host is able to ping your VM IP address, and then make sure you don't have a firewall on your host machine preventing you from connecting to your VM. And then make sure your VM doesn't have a firewall preventing foreign machines from connecting to it.

Comment: @jxh I already tried to ping my VM from my host and I was able to get a response successfully. I tried what you suggested and changed some of the firewall settings. I've included an edit in my post about what I've tried.

Comment: If `ping` works, does `netcat` or `telnet` work to reach the port you are trying to connect to? Also, are your sure your VM IP address is not being used by some other machine/device on your regular network?

Comment: Why don't you try turning iptables off and seeing if it works or not just to make sure the firewall isn't the cause? No route to host almost always means that the firewall is stopping you.

Comment: @jxh trying to telnet my VM from my host machine causes the same "connet error: No route to host" error. I would not know if my VM IP address is being used by some other device. Why would this matter and how can I check?

Comment: @dbeer Thanks for the suggestion. Something sure did change when I turned off iptables. Instead a "connect error: No route to host" error, running my client just hangs. Nothing happens or prints. It just hangs.

Comment: Your observations clearly indicate this is not a programming issue, but a network configuration issue. I am voting to close this question, but you should consult a different stack-exchange site to get help with your issue (e.g., server fault).